# How to change button's default color and add icon image in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

I want to add an image file at my button.
So i added it by changing

```xml
<Button
...
android:background="@drawable/button"
...
/>
```

By the way the default color of android studio covered my whole button icon.

I changed backgroundTint and iconTint. But it was not the right solution.
I changed them into not only `"#A9A9A9"` but also `"@null"`, but it never changed to original icon image.
Any advice?

Comment: is "@drawable/button" a png image or is it a drawable or a vector drawable ?, if it is a png image then you cannot change the color of it, if it is a drawable or a vector drawable you can change it with the "android:backgroundTint" attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
android:backgroundTint="@drawable/button"
```

Comment: Sorry to say this. but it doesn't work.